# incorporate values from one xml file into another.

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, xslt-2.0, transformation

I have the following xml files (let's call them paragraph.xml and sentence.xml).

**Paragraph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<paragraphs>
     <paragraph id="par_1" parBegin="1" parEnd="100" par_type="intro" context="positive"/>
     <paragraph id="par_2" parBegin="101" parEnd="170" par_type="elaboration" context="negative"/>
     <paragraph id="par_3" parBegin="171" parEnd="210" par_type="elaboration" context="positive"/>
     <paragraph id="par_4" parBegin="211" parEnd="280" par_type="conclusion" context="neutral"/>
```

In paragraph.xml file, the attribute "**parBegin**" shows the word-number with which the paragraph starts and "**parEnd**" shows the number of the word where paragraph ends. As an example, the first paragraph element starts with word **1** (the value of parBegin attribute) and ends with word **100** (the first paragraph has 100 words).

The other xml file **sentence.xml** has information about the sentences of the same text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <sentences>
     <sentence id="sent_1" sentBegin="1" sentEnd="15" sent_type="question"/>
     <sentence id="sent_2" sentBegin="16" sentEnd="30" sent_type="imperative"/>
     <sentence id="sent_3" sentBegin="31" sentEnd="37" sent_type="confirmation"/>
     ...
     <sentence id="sent_15" sentBegin="120" sentEnd="125" sent_type="conclusion" />
```

In sentence.xml file, the attribute "**sentBegin**" shows the word-number with which the sentence starts and "**sentEnd**" shows the number of the word where paragraph ends. As en example, the first sentence element starts with word **1** (the value of sentBegin attribute) and ends with word **15**. The sentence with **id="sent_15"** starts with word 120 (sentBegin="120") and ends in word 125 (sentEnd="125").

**What I want to do is to check to which paragraph each sentence belongs.** In another word, to compare the value of the attribute **@sentEnd** with the value of the attribute **@parEnd**. If **@sentEnd** is bigger than **@parBegin**  and smaller than **@parEnd** of a paragraph element, it shows that the sentence belongs to that paragraph. As an example, the sentEnd value of the sentence (id="sent_15") is 125 (**sentEnd="125"**) which is bigger than the **@parBegin** (parBegin="101") value of paragraph with **id="par_2"** and smaller than its **@parEnd** (parEnd="170") values. This shows that sentence **id="sent_15"** belongs to paragraph **id="par_2"**. The desired output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <sentences>
     <sentence id="sent_1" sentBegin="1" sentEnd="15" sent_type="question" paragraph="par_1" par_type="intro"/>
     <sentence id="sent_2" sentBegin="16" sentEnd="30" sent_type="imperative" paragraph="par_1" par_type="intro"/>
     <sentence id="sent_3" sentBegin="31" sentEnd="37" sent_type="confirmation" paragraph="par_1" par_type="intro"/>
     ...
     <sentence id="sent_15" sentBegin="120" sentEnd="125" sent_type="conclusion" paragraph="par_2" par_type="elaboration" />
```

Thanks a lot for your feedback/solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can simply select the right `paragraph` with a predicate:

```
  <xsl:template match="sentence">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates 
             select="@*, 
                     $paragraph-doc/paragraphs/paragraph[xs:integer(@parBegin) &lt;= xs:integer(current()/@sentBegin) and xs:integer(@parEnd) >= xs:integer(current()/@sentEnd)]/(@id, @par_type)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

In the following I have inlined the paragraph document in a parameter but you could of course load it instead using the `doc` function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="paragraph-doc">
    <paragraphs>
         <paragraph id="par_1" parBegin="1" parEnd="100" par_type="intro" context="positive"/>
         <paragraph id="par_2" parBegin="101" parEnd="170" par_type="elaboration" context="negative"/>
         <paragraph id="par_3" parBegin="171" parEnd="210" par_type="elaboration" context="positive"/>
         <paragraph id="par_4" parBegin="211" parEnd="280" par_type="conclusion" context="neutral"/>
    </paragraphs>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="sentence">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates 
             select="@*, 
                     $paragraph-doc/paragraphs/paragraph[xs:integer(@parBegin) &lt;= xs:integer(current()/@sentBegin) and xs:integer(@parEnd) >= xs:integer(current()/@sentEnd)]/(@id, @par_type)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="paragraph/@id">
      <xsl:attribute name="paragraph" select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQZ is an XSLT 3 sample, for XSLT 2 you would need to replace the used `xsl:mode` declaration with the identity transformation template.

As a refinement or alternative to the above we could key the `paragraph` elements on `@parBegin to @parEnd` and then use that key to find the relevant paragraph from a sentence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="paragraph-doc">
    <paragraphs>
         <paragraph id="par_1" parBegin="1" parEnd="100" par_type="intro" context="positive"/>
         <paragraph id="par_2" parBegin="101" parEnd="170" par_type="elaboration" context="negative"/>
         <paragraph id="par_3" parBegin="171" parEnd="210" par_type="elaboration" context="positive"/>
         <paragraph id="par_4" parBegin="211" parEnd="280" par_type="conclusion" context="neutral"/>
    </paragraphs>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:key name="par-ref" match="paragraph" use="@parBegin to @parEnd"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="sentence">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates 
             select="@*, 
                     key('par-ref', xs:integer(@sentEnd), $paragraph-doc)/(@id, @par_type)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="paragraph/@id">
      <xsl:attribute name="paragraph" select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQZ/2